# Heroku: update database plan, then delete the first one

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I updated my DB plan on heroku quite some time ago, following this clear tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrade-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups

So now I have 2 DB running:

```
$ heroku pg:info
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Crane
Status:      Available
Data Size:   26.1 MB
Tables:      52
PG Version:  9.2.6
Connections: 8
Fork/Follow: Available
Rollback:    Unsupported
Created:     2013-11-04 09:42 UTC
Region:      eu-west-1
Maintenance: not required

=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ORANGE_URL
Plan:        Dev
Status:      available
Connections: 0
PG Version:  9.2.7
Created:     2013-08-13 20:05 UTC
Data Size:   11.8 MB
Tables:      49
Rows:        7725/10000 (In compliance, close to row limit) - refreshing
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
Region:      Europe
```

I keep receiving mails saying that I'm close to rate limit on `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ORANGE_URL`. I'd rather delete it, but I'd like to make sure I'm not going to loose any data. Heroku is not clear about it:

> The original database will continue to run (and incur charges) even after the upgrade. If desired, remove it after the upgrade is successful.

But can I be 100% sure that all the data in the `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ORANGE_URL` is duplicated in the `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY_URL`? Because if `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ORANGE_URL` were a follower of `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY_URL`, its data should be as big as the first one.

So I just need a confirmation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like the upgrade dumped and reloaded the DB. So the new DB is a *copy* of the old one. If that's the case, it will contain all data from the old one *at the time it was copied* - but if you kept on adding new data to the old database, that data wouldn't appear in the new one.

I strongly recommend that before dropping the DB you:

- Disable access to it except for `pg_dump`
- Dump it with `pg_dump` (or use Heroku's tools to do that)
- ... and only then delete it.

That way, if you discover you've made a mistake, you have a dump to restore.

Comment: Nice thanks. Any idea how I can disable the access except for `pg_dump`?

Comment: On a "real" PostgreSQL install you'd use `pg_hba.conf`. On Heroku ... you'd need to check their documentation.